# What is the difference between shared_ptr<int> and shared_ptr<int[]>?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a class variable `ptr`, I want it to point to the first element of my 1D `int` array.

What is the difference between these two statements, and which one should I use?

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr1;
shared_ptr<int[]> ptr2;
```

Comment: Do you know what `[]` usually implies for a variable? And if the array already exists, do you know what is implied by using a smart pointer?

Answer (score 4):

`shared_ptr<int>` holds an `int*` pointer to a *single* `int`. That `int` is expected to be allocated with the `new` operator (preferably via a call to `std::make_shared<int>(value)`), and will be freed with the `delete` operator.

`shared_ptr<int[]>` holds an `int*` pointer to the 1st element of an `int[]` *array*. That array is expected to be allocated with the `new[]` operator (preferably via a call to `std::make_shared<int[]>(size)`), and will be freed with the `delete[]` operator.